# How to stop a Httpclient in c#

Tags: c#, post, get, httpclient

In my wpf project I have this:

```
private async void RequestStart(HttpClient client, Task task)
    {

        NetworkModel nmodel = new NetworkModel();
        NetworkModel1.Rootobject tryModel = await nmodel.ClientStock();

        var apiClient = new APIClient();
        Task<string> getResponseColourSize = apiClient.GetAsync($"https://www.try.com/{id}.json");

        var ATCvalues = new Dictionary<string, string>
        {
            { "style", sizeColourID.colourID.ToString() },
            { "size", sizeColourID.sizeID.ToString() },

        };

        var ATCcontent = new FormUrlEncodedContent(ATCvalues);

        var ATCresponse = await client.PostAsync($"https://www.try.com/{id}/cart.json", ATCcontent);

        var ATCresponseString = await ATCresponse.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

        System.Windows.MessageBox.Show(ATCresponseString);
    }
```

> Firstly I make a GET request and then after several other GET requests, I make a POST request

How would I be able to make it so that on a button click the user would be able to stop the request. The problem is that I cannot find something online to satisfy this. The only things I have found are for either GET or POST requests. Would I just need to stop the RequestStart altogether? Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: PostAsync(Uri, HttpContent, CancellationToken) is what you need: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpclient.postasync?view=netframework-4.8#System_Net_Http_HttpClient_PostAsync_System_Uri_System_Net_Http_HttpContent_System_Threading_CancellationToken_

Comment: @PoulBak How would I be able to use it for the POST request because I have looked online but everyone seems to have a different answer which doesn't work for my example because I would have to call the cancel token as a private property to be able to call on it in the button click

Comment: You create a CancellationTokenSource object - and pass it's Token property to the PostAsync method. Then you call the CancellationTokenSource's Cancel method  then PostAsync will be cancelled. (The CancellationTokenSource should be a field of the class).